# Transcription du mot « recevoir »

Tags: phonétique, e-caduc

J'ai trouvé la transcription suivante du mot « recevoir » : /ʁəsəvwaʁ/. Ma question, c'est pourquoi le deuxième « e » caduc est-il maintenu ? Pour autant que je sache, le premier est maintenu parce qu'il est au début du mot et le deuxième doit tomber parce qu'il n'y a qu'une seule consonne devant lui ( comme par exemple dans les mots : acheter, samedi, maintenant... ). Quelle est la règle qui explique ce cas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La séquence [sv] est très rare en français. J'imagine que ça peut expliquer la réalisation plus fréquente de ce *e*, en particulier quand le mot *recevoir* est prononcé seul.

*Rec**e**voir* n'est d'ailleurs pas le seul mot concerné, c'est la même chose avec *conc**e**voir*, *déc**e**voir*, *ens**e**velir*, *perc**e**voir*.

Deux rares exemples où un *e* placé entre [s] et [v] n'est pas réalisé en Français « standard »  sont les mots composés :

> Assuranc**e**-vie
>
> Vic**e**-versa

Quand *recevoir* est utilisé dans une phrase, ce *e* peut disparaître, comme par exemple dans :

> J'aime recevoir des amis.

Le *e* est prononcé dans le cas d'une prononciation soignée mais est sinon souvent omis.